# limit to one result causes my php sql query to return false

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

Whenever I try to limit the results I get the query returns false. However When I do not limit the results it works fine just with multiple results.

Any ideas?

```
$locationsQuery='select Firstname, Lastname, Location , DateandTime from locations where
    username=? ORDER BY DateandTime desc limit 1';
     $results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $locationsQuery,
    array($desiredusername));
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))

    {
    $date_time = ($row['DateandTime']);
    $formated_date = $date_time->format('d/m/y H:i');
    echo '<p> User '.$row['Firstname'].' '.$row['Lastname'].' is at location:
    '.$row['Location']. ' at '. $formated_date;'</p>';
    }
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `sql-srv` doesnt use `limit` it uses `top`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about top but it still fails.

Comment: That is the wrong usage, `sql-srv` puts the top in the column listings. Pay close attention on the dup, `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Persons;`.

Comment: Ahhh. Cheers Chris, greatly appreciated.